# Transaction included in block whereas log not generated

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, dapps

When I sent a transaction continuously below 27 Transaction Per Second (TPS) then all transaction is included in a block and generated the log as expected.
Whereas When TPS increases above 27 then included transaction not generated the log (empty log) when I checked in the particular block using transaction hash.

---

Edit:
 Contract is a simple function with 12 arguments and which have to store in the state and finally emit the log after updating the state in each transaction without any validation.

Comment: Could you show smart contract source code and some transaction that was included but didn't generate log?

Comment: Without the contract is hard to say something definitive. Unless you have done something on purpose usually transactions do not depend on each other so increasing the number of them should not cause them to fail. But it is possible for transactions to have explicit dependencies and cause other to fail.